# Converting solr 4.3 Solr.xml and schema files to solr 7.1 format

Tags: solr

I have a Solr 4.3 cluster where schema files and solr.xml are stored in git. 
The nodes are build with a script that creates all the cores on the file system and copies the schema and related files to the cores. Then we start Solr and import the data.

I can see that a lot has changed and I am looking for an example on have to script the cores using the new file format. I know the content off the data so we dont need any dynamic fields (ClassicIndexSchemaFactory).

So the answer could be in the form of a link to a git repro or some example files.

Hope that the question is specific enough to answer.

Current Solr.xml I have shortened the file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<solr persistent="true">
    <cores zkClientTimeout="${zkClientTimeout:15000}" hostContext="${hostContext:}" hostPort="${jetty.port:}" host="${host:}" adminPath="/admin/cores/"> 
        <core loadOnStartup="true" instanceDir="cores/entry_dada"           transient="false" name="entry_dada"/>       
        <core loadOnStartup="true" instanceDir="cores/entry_dade"           transient="false" name="entry_dade"/>
        <core loadOnStartup="true" instanceDir="cores/entry_daen"           transient="false" name="entry_daen"/>
        <core loadOnStartup="true" instanceDir="cores/entry_daes"           transient="false" name="entry_daes"/>
        <core loadOnStartup="true" instanceDir="cores/entry_dafr"           transient="false" name="entry_dafr"/>
        ... 

        <core loadOnStartup="true" instanceDir="cores/lemmaaccessorydata_da"    transient="false" name="lemmaaccessorydata_da"/>
        <core loadOnStartup="true" instanceDir="cores/lemma_da"                 transient="false" name="lemma_da"/>
        <core loadOnStartup="true" instanceDir="cores/lemmainflection_da"       transient="false" name="lemmainflection_da"/>
        ...
    </cores>
</solr>
```

Comment: so, you want to have a script as an answer? set of changes that you could code?

Comment: The answer could be a link to a git repo an article or some example files